# How to compare two maps by their values

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, compare, equals

How to compare two maps by their values? I have two maps containing equal values and want to compare them by their values. Here is an example:

```
    Map a = new HashMap();
    a.put("foo", "bar"+"bar");
    a.put("zoo", "bar"+"bar");

    Map b = new HashMap();
    b.put(new String("foo"), "bar"+"bar");
    b.put(new String("zoo"), "bar"+"bar");

    System.out.println("equals: " + a.equals(b));            // obviously false
```

How should I change the code to obtain a true?

Comment: Should be sane now that the two maps are the same in at least *one* sense...

Comment: @lewap: What exact sort of similarity are you looking for? Similarity by "this map has the same set of (key,value) mappings as that one"?

Comment: -1 - this question is totally ambiguous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your attempts to construct different strings using concatenation will fail as it's being performed at compile-time. Both of those maps have a single pair; each pair will have "foo" and "barbar" as the key/value, both using the same string reference.

Assuming you really want to compare the sets of values without any reference to keys, it's just a case of:

```
Set<String> values1 = new HashSet<>(map1.values());
Set<String> values2 = new HashSet<>(map2.values());
boolean equal = values1.equals(values2);
```

It's *possible* that comparing `map1.values()` with `map2.values()` would work - but it's also possible that the order in which they're returned would be used in the equality comparison, which isn't what you want.

Note that using a set has its own problems - because the above code would deem a map of {"a":"0", "b":"0"} and {"c":"0"} to be equal... the value sets are equal, after all.

If you could provide a stricter definition of what you want, it'll be easier to make sure we give you the right answer.

Comment: Why use additional space?

Comment: @Manu: To achieve the result which I believe the OP wants. Your answer compares keys as well as values. I believe the OP wants a map of `{"a"=1, "b"=2 }` to be equal to a map of `{"c"=2, "d"=1}` for example.

Comment: OP is being ambiguous on that part. If it's purely values comparison, it's uncertain [1] how he wants to handle duplicates [2] whether he wants to compare values by it's keys. Now, since your answer is 'accepted', looks like he wants to duplicates ignored value-comparison.

Comment: @Manu: Indeed. And that's why I asked for more clarification if possible, and explicitly gave an example using duplicates - but given that the OP accepted my answer, I assume that *is* what they were looking for.

Answer (score 35):

The correct way to compare maps for value-equality is to:

1. Check that the maps are the same size(!)
2. Get the set of *keys* from one map
3. For each key from that set you retrieved, check that the value retrieved from each map for that key is the same (if the key is absent from one map, that's a total failure of equality)

In other words (minus error handling):

```
boolean equalMaps(Map<K,V>m1, Map<K,V>m2) {
   if (m1.size() != m2.size())
      return false;
   for (K key: m1.keySet())
      if (!m1.get(key).equals(m2.get(key)))
         return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than `Map.equals`?

Comment: For value-equality, that's too strict a test.  It not only tests for value-equality, but also for key-value map equality.

Comment: @CPerkins: I guess I just don't see the point in only comparing values. It's missing at least one whole herd of elephants in the room; a differing map just *isn't* the same. @poly: Hmm, it isn't different. I suppose that's why that's what the equality operation is defined to be. :-) I think the original problem was caused by the questioner just updating the wrong map or something equally basic.

Comment: I agree with you about the point, but the OP seemed to be asking about value equality, not key-value map equality.  Otherwise there's no point in the question.

Comment: @CPerkins: Check the history of the question. In particular, in the original one the two maps were different because of a silly error and I'm beginning to suspect that the *real* answer to the question was to point out that error. +100 Meh.

Comment: @polygenelubricants (Long, long after the fact…) The real difference is that `Map.equals` is careful about `null` keys and values (and is a bit more efficient too).

Answer (score 6):

To see if two maps have the same values, you can do the following:

- Get their `Collection<V> values()` views
- Wrap into `List<V>`
- `Collections.sort` those lists
- Test if the two lists are `equals`

Something like this works (though its type bounds can be improved on):

```
static <V extends Comparable<V>>
boolean valuesEquals(Map<?,V> map1, Map<?,V> map2) {
    List<V> values1 = new ArrayList<V>(map1.values());
    List<V> values2 = new ArrayList<V>(map2.values());
    Collections.sort(values1);
    Collections.sort(values2);
    return values1.equals(values2);
}
```

Test harness:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("A", "B");
map1.put("C", "D");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map2.put("A", "D");
map2.put("C", "B");

System.out.println(valuesEquals(map1, map2)); // prints "true"
```

This is `O(N log N)` due to [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

#### See also:

- [`Collection<V> values()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29)

---

To test if the *keys* are equals is easier, because they're `Set<K>`:

```
map1.keySet().equals(map2.keySet())
```

#### See also:

- [`Set<K> keySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)

Comment: That won't help. If `map1` had (A=>B,C=>D), and `map2` had (A=>D,C=>B)  then they have the same values and keys (and might even enumerate them in the same order; that's not guaranteed!) but are still demonstrably different.

Comment: @Donald: added the sorted list version and your test harness; it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about ready-made Api's ... well Apache's commons. collections library has a [**CollectionUtils**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/index.html) class that provides easy-to-use methods for Collection manipulation/checking, such as intersection, difference, and union.

Answer (score 2):

All of these are returning equals. They arent actually doing a comparison, which is useful for sort. This will behave more like a comparator:

```
private static final Comparator stringFallbackComparator = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (!(o1 instanceof Comparable))
            o1 = o1.toString();
        if (!(o2 instanceof Comparable))
            o2 = o2.toString();
        return ((Comparable)o1).compareTo(o2);
    }
};

public int compare(Map m1, Map m2) {
    TreeSet s1 = new TreeSet(stringFallbackComparator); s1.addAll(m1.keySet());
    TreeSet s2 = new TreeSet(stringFallbackComparator); s2.addAll(m2.keySet());
    Iterator i1 = s1.iterator();
    Iterator i2 = s2.iterator();
    int i;
    while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext())
    {
        Object k1 = i1.next();
        Object k2 = i2.next();
        if (0!=(i=stringFallbackComparator.compare(k1, k2)))
            return i;
        if (0!=(i=stringFallbackComparator.compare(m1.get(k1), m2.get(k2))))
            return i;
    }
    if (i1.hasNext())
        return 1;
    if (i2.hasNext())
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but still relevant.

If you want to compare two maps by their values matching their keys, you can do as follows:

```
public static <K, V> boolean mapEquals(Map<K, V> leftMap, Map<K, V> rightMap) {
    if (leftMap == rightMap) return true;
    if (leftMap == null || rightMap == null || leftMap.size() != rightMap.size()) return false;
    for (K key : leftMap.keySet()) {
        V value1 = leftMap.get(key);
        V value2 = rightMap.get(key);
        if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
            continue;
        else if (value1 == null || value2 == null)
            return false;
        if (!value1.equals(value2))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @uı6ʎɹnɯlǝıuɐp Yes, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that there can be duplicate values the only way to do this is to put the values in lists, sort them and compare the lists viz:

```
List<String> values1 = new ArrayList<String>(map1.values());
List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<String>(map2.values());
Collections.sort(values1);
Collections.sort(values2);
boolean mapsHaveEqualValues = values1.equals(values2);
```

If values cannot contain duplicate values then you can either do the above without the sort using sets.

Comment: We all wish that `Collections.sort` is "fluid" (I think that's the term), but no, it returns `void`.

Comment: Err yes, my mistake.  Edited it to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "apache-common-like" tool to compare maps since the equality of 2 maps is very ambiguous and depends on the developer needs and the map implementation...

For exemple if you compare two hashmaps in java:
- You may want to just compare key/values are the same
- You may also want to compare if the keys are ordered the same way
- You may also want to compare if the remaining capacity is the same
... You can compare a lot of things!

What such a tool would do when comparing 2 different map implementations such that:
- One map allow null keys
- The other throw runtime exception on map2.get(null)

You'd better to implement your own solution according to what you really need to do, and i think you already got some answers above :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of equals in your example is obviously false because you are comparing the map a with some values in it with an empty map b (probably a copy and paste error). I recommend to use proper variable names (so you can avoid these kinds of errors) and make use of generics, too.

```
    Map<String, String> first = new HashMap<String, String>();
    first.put("f"+"oo", "bar"+"bar");
    first.put("fo"+"o", "bar"+"bar");

    Map second = new HashMap();
    second.put("f"+"oo", "bar"+"bar");
    second.put("fo"+"o", "bar"+"bar");

    System.out.println("equals: " + first.equals(second));
```

The concatenation of your strings doesn't have any effect because it will be done at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

@paweloque For Comparing two Map Objects in java, you can add the keys of a map to list and with those 2 lists you can use the methods retainAll() and removeAll() and add them to another common keys list and different keys list. Using the keys of the common list and different list you can iterate through map, using equals you can compare the maps.

The below code will give output like this:
Before {zoo=barbar, foo=barbar}
After {zoo=barbar, foo=barbar}
Equal: Before- barbar After- barbar
Equal: Before- barbar After- barbar

```
package com.demo.compareExample

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, String> beforeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        beforeMap.put("foo", "bar"+"bar");
        beforeMap.put("zoo", "bar"+"bar");

        Map<String, String> afterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        afterMap.put(new String("foo"), "bar"+"bar");
        afterMap.put(new String("zoo"), "bar"+"bar");

        System.out.println("Before "+beforeMap);
        System.out.println("After "+afterMap);

        List<String> beforeList = getAllKeys(beforeMap);

        List<String> afterList = getAllKeys(afterMap);

        List<String> commonList1 = beforeList;
        List<String> commonList2 = afterList;
        List<String> diffList1 = getAllKeys(beforeMap);
        List<String> diffList2 = getAllKeys(afterMap);

        commonList1.retainAll(afterList);
        commonList2.retainAll(beforeList);

        diffList1.removeAll(commonList1);
        diffList2.removeAll(commonList2);

        if(commonList1!=null & commonList2!=null) // athough both the size are same
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < commonList1.size(); i++) 
            {
                if ((beforeMap.get(commonList1.get(i))).equals(afterMap.get(commonList1.get(i)))) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Equal: Before- "+ beforeMap.get(commonList1.get(i))+" After- "+afterMap.get(commonList1.get(i)));
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Unequal: Before- "+ beforeMap.get(commonList1.get(i))+" After- "+afterMap.get(commonList1.get(i)));
                }
            }
        }
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(diffList1)) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < diffList1.size(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("Values present only in before map: "+beforeMap.get(diffList1.get(i)));
            }
        }
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(diffList2)) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < diffList2.size(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("Values present only in after map: "+afterMap.get(diffList2.get(i)));
            }
        }
    }

    /**getAllKeys API adds the keys of the map to a list */
    private static List<String> getAllKeys(Map<String, String> map1)
    {
        List<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (map1 != null) 
        {
            Iterator<String> mapIterator = map1.keySet().iterator();
            while (mapIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                key.add(mapIterator.next());
            }
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equalMaps(Map<?, ?> map1, Map<?, ?>map2) {

    if (map1==null || map2==null || map1.size() != map2.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (Object key: map1.keySet()) {
        if (!map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to do it in Java 8 streams below is the example.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CompareTwoMaps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<>();
        a.put("foo", "bar" + "bar");
        a.put("zoo", "bar" + "bar");

        Map<String, String> b = new HashMap<>();
        b.put(new String("foo"), "bar" + "bar");
        b.put(new String("zoo"), "bar" + "bar");

        System.out.println("result = " + areEqual(a, b));
    }

    private static boolean areEqual(Map<String, String> first, Map<String, String> second) {
        return first.entrySet().stream()
                .allMatch(e -> e.getValue().equals(second.get(e.getKey())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to compare two Maps then, below code may help you

```
(new TreeMap<String, Object>(map1).toString().hashCode()) == new TreeMap<String, Object>(map2).toString().hashCode()
```

Comment: This will not work. Different strings can have the same hashcode and the `==` operator compares object references. So it will never be true with two `new` instances. The correct answer is to use `equals`.

Comment: String.hashCode() will return int, so == will work fine. In reality, in this example, it will be very rare that same hash code will come for two different Maps. If not hashCode, we can use MD5.

Comment: Not if multiple strings can return the same hashcode - which is possible. Better to recommend something that works properly, not just "sometimes".