# How to Check list items having same data ? in android

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

i am developing an app to get some details from a web service and show them in a customized list view.i have used a Hashmap to put data which i get from the JSON object. In my list view i have a

- Person Name
- ID [not visible to the user]
- start time  , end time
- date and two buttons

now i just wanna check weather there are data in the list which is having same date and same time slots. as an example is there any data which is having

- date : "2013/6/7"
- start time : 8.00  end time 9.00

i have no idea how to do it..can i check it in my hash map ? or can someone give me a idea how to do this..please

Comment: Hay u have to compare lite item object

Comment: can you give me an example please :)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674021/how-to-compare-two-maps-by-their-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this.

```
public HashMap getDuplicateValues(HashMap in)
{
// Clone input HashMap because we're removing stuff from it
in = (HashMap)in.clone();
HashMap rval = new HashMap();
Object[] keys = in.keySet().toArray();

// iterate through all keys
for(int x=0;x<keys.length;x++) {
  Object value = in.get(keys[x]);
  in.remove(keys[x]);
  // if value is in input HashMap, store it in duplicate HashMap because it has another value
  if(in.containsValue(value)) {
     rval.put(keys[x],value);
  }
  // if value is in duplicate HashMap, store it also because it HAD another value earlier
  if(rval.containsValue(value)) {
     rval.put(keys[x],value);
  }
  }

 return(rval);
  }
```

Test code:

```
 HashMap map = new HashMap();

 map.put("1","2");
map.put("2","1");
map.put("3","8");
map.put("4","4");
map.put("5","6");
map.put("6","8");
map.put("7","3");
map.put("8","4");
map.put("9","4");

HashMap dups = getDuplicateValues(map);

System.out.println("MAP = "+map);
System.out.println("DUP = "+dups);
```

Output:

```
MAP = {3=8, 2=1, 1=2, 7=3, 6=8, 5=6, 4=4, 9=4, 8=4}
DUP = {3=8, 6=8, 4=4, 9=4, 8=4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether string is there in list by using following method.

```
arraylist.contains(stringtocheck);
```

Comment: actually i need to check there are records which having same date or same time slots..and is there any records that having same date or same time slots i need to show that records in a new list..

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateSearch = "2013/6/7"


boolean dateExists = hm.containsValue(dateSearch);
        if (dateExists)
        {
             // get values
             for(int k = 0; k < hm.size(); k++){
             map = (HashMap)hm.get(k);
             }
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
```