# What is the best way to iterate two hashmap in same loop in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

What's the best way to iterate over the below two maps together? I want to compare two maps values which are strings and have to get the keys and values.

```
HashMap<String, String> map1;
HashMap<String, String> map2;
```

Comment: match what, insertion order will not be same in two `hashmap`, so element by element comparison not possible. EIther iterate first , and get the key values from 2nd and compare

Comment: is it need to compare only maps value , not keys right??

Comment: Hi ankur /ParaSara, I have to compare values in both maps.

Comment: Maybe you should be using LinkedHashMap, so that the iterators will run in order of insertion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two maps by their values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674021/how-to-compare-two-maps-by-their-values)

Comment: thanks Patricia.I want to fetch the keys and values also in string.
@Kenneth-its not duplicate of that..i want to know the process of iteration

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There really isn't a better option than

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : map1.entrySet() {
  String key = entry1.getKey();
  String value1 = entry1.getValue();
  String value2 = map2.get(key); 
  // do whatever with value1 and value2 
}
```

Comment: If they're both LHMs _and_ you know they have the same iteration order, you could use a pair of iterators in lockstep.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, there are several reasonable options:

1. **Just compare the contents of two maps**

   [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a [`Maps.difference()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference(java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map)) utility that gives you a [`MapDifference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html) instance letting you inspect exactly what is the same or different between two maps.
2. **Iterate over their entries simultaneously**

   If you just want to iterate over the entries in two maps simultaneously, it's no different than iterating over any other `Collection`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3137944/113632) goes into more detail, but a basic solution would look like this:

   ```
   Preconditions.checkState(map1.size() == map2.size());
   Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter1 = map1.entrySet().iterator();
   Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter2 = map2.entrySet().iterator();
   while(iter1.hasNext() || iter2.hasNext()) {
     Entry<String, String> e1 = iter1.next();
     Entry<String, String> e2 = iter2.next();
     ...
   }
   ```

   Note there is no guarantee these entries will  be in the same order (and therefore `e1.getKey().equals(e2.getKey())` may well be false).
3. **Iterate over their keys to pair up their values**

   If you need the keys to line up, iterate over the union of both maps' keys:

   ```
   for(String key : Sets.union(map1.keySet(), map2.keySet()) {
     // these could be null, if the maps don't share the same keys
     String value1 = map1.get(key);
     String value2 = map2.get(key);
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```java
for (String key : map1.keySet()) {
  if (map2.containsKey(key)) {
    // do whatever
  } else {
    // map2 doesn't have entry with map1 key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case if maps are the same sizes

```
IntStream.range(0, map1.size()).forEach(i -> map1.get(i).equals(map2.get(i));
```