# .equal doesn't work for list of list even if they are equal

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashmap, equals

So when I am checking freqMap1.values() and freqMap2.values() have the same values but when I check it with .equals it returns false. I am baffled as to how fix this problem:

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/26/16.
 */
import java.util.*;

public class IsomorphicStrings {
    //the words "abca" and "zbxz" are isomorphic

    public static boolean areIsomorphic(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> freqMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> freqMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
            if (freqMap1.containsKey(s1.charAt(i))) {
                freqMap1.get(s1.charAt(i)).add(i);
            } else {
                freqMap1.put(s1.charAt(i), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)));
            }

        }

        for (int i=0; i<s2.length(); i++) {
            if (freqMap2.containsKey(s2.charAt(i))) {
                freqMap2.get(s2.charAt(i)).add(i);
            } else {
                freqMap2.put(s2.charAt(i), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(freqMap1.values());
        System.out.println(freqMap2.values());
        return freqMap1.values().equals(freqMap2.values());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="foo";
        String s2="app";
        System.out.println(areIsomorphic(s1, s2));
    }
}
```

This is the output I get from prints:

```
[[0], [1, 2]]
[[0], [1, 2]]
false
```

Comment: Mona , You may find your pleasure [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674021/how-to-compare-two-maps-by-their-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`values()` returns a `Collection` implementation that doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`. Therefore, you are comparing object references instead of the contents of the `Collection`s.

You can compare them by converting these `Collection`s to `List`s before calling `equals` :

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(freqMap1.values()).equals(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>freqMap2.values()))
```

This will return `true` only if both `values()` `Collection`s contain the same elements in the same iteration order. If you don't care about the order and about duplicate values, you can convert the `values()` `Collection`s to `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`. Now you'll get `true` if both `values()` `Collection`s contain the same unique elements, regardless of iteration order.

In Java 7+, the following would work:

```
return new ArrayList<>(freqMap1.values()).equals(new ArrayList<>(freqMap2.values()));
```

Comment: Same is true for keyset() comparison too.

Comment: @ShivV No, it's not. `keySet()` returns an instance of a sub-class of `AbstractSet`, which overrides `equals`, so you can compare `Set`s returned by `keySet()` with `equals`.

Comment: my apologies. you're right.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm not sure. That part was added by the OP, not me.

Comment: @Eran I am using Java 8 that is why I wrote it works in Java 8 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are comparing `List` of `List` with `equals`. The following solves the problem for me.

```
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> map1Values = new ArrayList(freqMap1.values());
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> map2Values = new ArrayList(freqMap2.values());        

    if(map1Values.get(i).size() != map2Values.get(i)){
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = true;

    for(int i=0;i<map1Values.size() && result;i++){
        boolean tmp = Objects.equals(map1Values.get(i), map2Values.get(i));
        result = result && tmp;
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: I count at least 4 bugs in this, 3 of which would be fixed by using `map1Values.equals(map2.values())` instead of the for loop.

Comment: Yes I figured `result` was returning the logical value of the last assignment and fixed this issue. What are the other 3 bugs?

Comment: 1) `List<ArrayList> map2Values = new ArrayList(freqMap1.values());` - you are using `freqMap1` instead of `freqMap2`.

Comment: 2) You don't check that the lists are the same size, so you will either not compare all elements, or get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, depending upon which is the bigger list.

Comment: 3) You compare `map1Values.get(i)` to `map1Values.get(i)`, which is obviously true (unless `map1Values.get(i)` is null, IWC you get a `NullPointerException`).

Comment: 4) Raw types. Not quite a bug, because you don't need anything more specific than `Object`; but it's worth fixing.

Comment: You can also make it fast break upon finding that some elements aren't equal, by changing the loop guard to `i<map1Values.size() && result` (or using `if (!tmp) return`).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I fixed the code snippet. I particularly liked your last comment on changing the loop guard. 1 and 3 were typos. By fixing raw types did you mean e.g. changing `List<ArrayList<Integer>>` to `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`? I'd like to know more about this.

Comment: `new ArrayList(...)` -> `new ArrayList<>(...)`.

Comment: You've not actually fixed 3) - you would need to use `Objects.equal(map1Values.get(i), map2Values.get(i))` (or equivalent) to be null-safe.

Comment: That's a good point. Done.